# How to generate data in python pandas for promotion planning use-case?

Tags: python, pandas, simulation, data-generation, test-data

Background : The business objective is to build a ML model which predicts lift in profit based on historical performance of the product during both promotional period as well as non-promotional periods.

I have built a ML model which predicts profit on daily level for each asin based on historical data using following inputs : Date, Product ID, Promotion flag , Promotion type, discount percent, current price.

Now I want to generate inference data by building a dataset which has all combinations of productID and promotion types along with several levels of discount percent for each day in the future. Is there a way to do this in pandas ?

Conditions : Given a date range (for ex. 3/17/23 - 3/27/23), promotion types - 3 types of promotions (bd,pd,ld), discount percent [0,5,10]

generate data for each day in the date range for each productID with different combinations of promotion type and discount percent.

Expected dataframe output :

This is just an example for two dates (3/17 and 3/18), 1 productID and all combinations for promotion type and discount percent. I want to create this for entire range of dates for each productID.

[Expected output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wziUO.png)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). This site is not a code-writing or tutoring service, it is best used when you have a specific problem with written code. Your question, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Show me a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example of the expected output you provided, here is a simple way to do it: list the different values you want to see in your dataframe, generate all combinations using `itertools.product`, and finally create the dataframe with the columns you want.

```py
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd

# Configuration
products_ids = [1, 2, 3]
date_range = ["2023-03-17", "2023-03-27"]
discount_types = ["bd", "pd", "ld"]
discount_prct = [0, 5, 10]

# Get all dates in range
all_dates = pandas.date_range(date_range[0], date_range[1], freq='d')

# Get all combinations
combinations = product(products_ids, all_dates, discount_types, discount_prct)

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(combinations, columns=["ProductID", "Date", "DiscountType", "DiscountPercent"])
```

Here are the 15th first rows:

|  | ProductID | Date | DiscountType | DiscountPercent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | bd | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | bd | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | bd | 10 |
| 3 | 1 | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | pd | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | pd | 5 |
| 5 | 1 | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | pd | 10 |
| 6 | 1 | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | ld | 0 |
| 7 | 1 | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | ld | 5 |
| 8 | 1 | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | ld | 10 |
| 9 | 1 | 2023-03-18 00:00:00 | bd | 0 |
| 10 | 1 | 2023-03-18 00:00:00 | bd | 5 |
| 11 | 1 | 2023-03-18 00:00:00 | bd | 10 |
| 12 | 1 | 2023-03-18 00:00:00 | pd | 0 |
| 13 | 1 | 2023-03-18 00:00:00 | pd | 5 |
| 14 | 1 | 2023-03-18 00:00:00 | pd | 10 |